# How can we use contextfilter in saga to filter command/event(message) based on some condition?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit, saga

Masstransit Saga : Have some same events(message) in two different saga workflows, how can we use context filter in saga to filter command/event(message) based on some condition?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a ContentFilter, you could just add a condition on the state machine.

```
During(SomeState,
    When(SomeEvent, x => x.Property == 'Something')
        .Then(...));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I was also implementing the same way by adding condition to each event .Since I have some 6 to 7  events which are in both sagas, was wondering if there is any way we could set up something in Configuration in Saga like we do it for Consumer instead of adding the condition for each and every event?

Comment: Not that I could really recommend, as you'd have logic spread out across filters and state machine logic. You can certainly create a message filter for the pipe if you want though.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. For now, I created a custom filter for my scenario and it worked fine.